# Hi guys, i want to install expo on my PC (windows 10) i get the following errors

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm-install

I tried to reinstall node.js, tried to "npm i expo-cli" (worked) and then "expo start" but didn't worked, same errors, i also looked at some question people asked before me but didn't worked.
i need it according youtube video I'm learning from , for react native.

[image: expo start]

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: Please share the error you are getting with expo start.

Comment: If it's help you then can you first install node.js(LTS version) & Git and after that install expo cli. npm install --global expo-cli

Comment: @JohnOcean i did read the message and it didn't work, I have tried to download node.js + Git again and didn't work, and i get the error  in the photo i added.